# Is there any way to play .flv viles on VideoView or anything surface?

Tags: android

I have following code for playing video from SDCard:

```
mVideoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
MediaController mc=new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);

String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Media/b.flv";
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.start();
```

It is the working code for .mp4 files, but it doesn't work for .flv. Is there any way how can I play .flv videos from SDCard? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), Android does not natively support the `.flv` container format.  This limits your options to:

1. Convert the video to some other format (like MPEG-4).
2. Find a library that can handle `.flv` videos directly.
3. Write a library that can handle `.flv` videos directly.
4. Use the Android Flash Player to play it.